# Animating scollbars when container height is changed

Tags: jquery, css

So I have a container with overflow-y: scroll. The container's height can change, most often it will be reduced. The change will be animated using jQuery. But when container is animated, the scrollbar disappears and it only reappears when the animation is complete. Is there anyway to change the dimensions of the scrollbar alongside the container's animation?

Here's an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SPLt2/

Comment: I dont think it is, since the scroll bars are part of browser ui and are not able to be changed, if you can't change its colours [presentation], you deffenetly not be able to do something as advanced as it's actions, or events :)

Comment: A brilliant Idea would be to just add a couple images to manipulate it, or make it look as if it was the scrollbar without the handler :) and it would look like the handler has disappeared to calculate things, and appears again at the end :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `animate` automatically sets the style to `overflow: hidden`.

You can circumvent this by overriding the style with a step function:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#container').animate(
        {'height': '100px'}, 
        { step: function() { $(this).css("overflow-y", "scroll") } }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And if the scrollbar doesn't stay around after a `step` (like I experienced) add a `complete` function to it.

Like this :

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#container').animate(
        {'height': '100px'}, 
        { step: function() { $(this).css("overflow-y", "scroll") } },
        { complete: function() { $(this).css("overflow-y", "scroll") } }
    );
});
```

Have a look at http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2648 for more informations.